# Leaflet L.Print (Mapfish) cannot set map scale

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, mapfish

I am trying to print a map using the MapFish Print extension of Geoserver in Leaflet (L.print). I configured the .yaml file to suit my needs but the scale of the map doesn't change no matter my settings.

On the printed map it always displays at 1:2000000.

Any idea how to enforce the map scale on the print tool?

`//Create a PRINT provider
    var printProvider = L.print.provider({
    capabilities: printConfig,
    method: 'GET',
    autoLoad: true,
    dpi: 300,
    legends: true,
    outputFormat: 'pdf',
    //layout:"A4 Landscape",
    pages: [{center: [46, 45.5],
            scale: 10000,
            dpi: 300,
            geodetic: true}],
    customParams: {
              mapTitle: 'title here',
              comment: 'here we can include a comment regarding the map - standard text'
          } });`

```
//Create Print Control
var printControl = L.control.print({
provider: printProvider
});        
map.addControl(printControl);`
```